# C++ programming, Iterator is a pointer even it is not declared a pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Consider the following lines

```
std::map<char,int> mymap;
std::map<char,int>::iterator it; /* not std::map<char,int>::iterator *it; */
```

In the second line even thought it is not declared as a pointer how are the elements are accessed using the arrow operator ( -> ) like bellow

```
std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
```

Comment: The same way you can use `<<` with `std::cout`: operator overloading.

Comment: That's how iterators are supposed to work, ***like*** pointers even though they aren't pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload `->` operator for your class and this exactly what happens here.

Another example:

```
class Hello
{
public:
    void Show()
    {
        printf("Hello, world!");
    }
};

class MyClass
{
private:
    Hello hello;

public:

    Hello * operator -> ()
    {
        return &hello;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MyClass m;

    m->Show();
}
```

Comment: So using the dot (.) operator will it work std::cout << it.first << " => " << it.second << '\n';

Comment: @Dinesh Why don't you simply try?

Comment: @Dinesh As iterators are supposed to work like pointers, they do of course have a dereference operator defined as well, so you can do `(*it).first`. However, the iterators themselves are basically "black boxes", how they are implemented is not specified, only their interface (which overloaded operators they should support etc) and their behavior (like what should happen when you increment it).

Comment: @Spook I tried and getting this map.cpp:35: error: 'struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<char* const, char*> >' has no member named 'first'

Comment: So it simply means, that you can't do that :) When you use `->`, iterator returns you something, what has a member called `first` and that's why this code works correctly. But the iterator itself doesn't have a field `first`.

Comment: An iterator is a thing, which is supposed to *look like* a pointer, though it is not a pointer. That's why you can perform operations like `->`, `(*iter).sth` etc. But that's only because it is prepared to handle these correctly. You cannot exchange `->` with `.`, because these two operators works completely differently (and AFAIK `.` operator is not overloadable).